# Saving spider results to database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, web-scraping, lxml

Currently thinking about a good way to save my scraped data into a database.

App flow:

1. Run spider (data scraper), file located in spiders/
2. When data has been collected successfully save the data/items (title, link, pubDate) to the database by use of the class in pipeline.py

**I would like your help with on how to save the scraped data (title, link, pubDate) from spider.py into the database through pipeline.py, currently I have nothing connecting these files together. When the data has been successfully scraped pipelines needs to be notified, receive the data and save it**

I'm very thankful for your help

**Spider.py**

```
import urllib.request
import lxml.etree as ET   

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
tree = ET.parse(opener.open('https://nordfront.se/feed'))


items = [{'title': item.find('title').text, 'link': item.find('link').text, 'pubdate': item.find('pubDate').text} for item in tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item")]

for item in items:
    print(item['title'], item['link'], item['pubdate'])
```

**Models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
import datetime

import settings


def db_connect():
    """
    Performs database connection using database settings from settings.py.
    Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    """
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

# <--snip-->

def create_presstv_table(engine):

    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

def create_nordfront_table(engine):

    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

def _get_date():
    return datetime.datetime.now()


class Nordfront(DeclarativeBase):
    """Sqlalchemy deals model"""
    __tablename__ = "nordfront"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    description = Column('description', String, nullable=True)
    link = Column('link', String, unique=True)
    date = Column('date', String, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column('created_at', DateTime, default=_get_date)
```

**Pipeline.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Nordfront, db_connect, create_nordfront_table

    class NordfrontPipeline(object):
        """Pipeline for storing scraped items in the database"""
        def __init__(self):
            """
            Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
            Creates deals table.
            """
            engine = db_connect()
            create_nordfront_table(engine)
            self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)




        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            """Save data in the database.

            This method is called for every item pipeline component.

            """
            session = self.Session()
            deal = Nordfront(**item)

            if session.query(Nordfront).filter_by(link=item['link']).first() == None:
                try:
                    session.add(deal)
                    session.commit()
                except:
                    session.rollback()
                    raise
                finally:
                    session.close()

                return item
```

**Settings.py**

```
DATABASE = {'drivername': 'postgres',
            'host': 'localhost',
            'port': '5432',
            'username': 'toothfairy',
            'password': 'password123',
            'database': 'news'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, this is a Scrapy-specific question. If so, you just need to [activate your pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component) in `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproj.pipeline.NordfrontPipeline': 100
}
```

This would let the engine know to send the crawled items to the pipeline (see [control flow](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#overview)):

[image]

---

If we are not talking about Scrapy, then, call `process_item()` directly from your spider:

```
from pipeline import NordfrontPipeline

...

pipeline = NordfrontPipeline()
for item in items:
    pipeline.process_item(item, None)
```

<sup>You may also remove the `spider` argument from the `process_item()` pipeline method since it is not used.</sup>

Comment: Hi Alecxe, I am not using Scrapy in my project but I know that Scrapy has similar functionality which I am looking for, however I feel that Scrapy feels a little bit overkill for this project. (I have tried it)

Comment: @Toothfairy well, I don't think it is an overkill - at least, the control and data flow is already there. Why reinvent the wheel and write your own web-scraping framework? Thanks.

Comment: I am simply looking for a way to get this pipeline running without heavy library

Comment: Because I am also a beginner trying to learn Python, in Scrapy there is too much magic :)

Comment: @Toothfairy okay, well, then instantiate  the pipeline object before the loop `pipeline = NordfrontPipeline()` and call `process_item()` inside the loop: `pipeline.process_item(item, None)`.

Comment: @Toothfairy I've also edited the answer and provided a simple example.